# How to install SQLite or other DB besides MySQL on hosted server or local XAMPP

Tags: linux, mysql, arch-linux

I am on Linux and I do have SQLite 3, but I want to use it with XAMPP.

Let's say:

1. Open localhost from browser
2. Fill a small form
3. Send the form to a perl script
4. The perl script should interact with SQLite instead MySQL(LAMPP default)
5. Show some records from SQLite.

The second question is: can I install SQLite on my ISP-provided host (apparently LAMPP too)?

I have issues with MySQL on my arch Linux and just can't get it to work. I really don't know why.

```
[ilian@myhost ~]$ sudo mysqld
Password: 
120614 11:40:33 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

120614 11:40:33 [ERROR] Aborting

120614 11:40:33 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

[ilian@myhost ~]$ sudo mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[ilian@myhost ~]$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[ilian@myhost ~]$ mysql
mysql                       mysql_find_rows
```

So I did not get any info about that error, but if smebody could help me solve either problems: making MySQL work or help me install other DB on XAMPP I`ll be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You should never run MySQL as root, that's why you're getting the first error. If you read it carefully, it tells you clearly what's wrong.

Secondly, SQLite is an *embedded* database, which means it doesn't run as a service like MySQL. It's designed for single-user applications (think apps on a smartphone).

Comment: Well, I`ve managed to login with mysql -u root -p. However, I`ve added to user 'localhost' and my user name. I am interested, will I be able to use it form localhost now? Considering the example with the html form in my post?

Comment: Running any service as a privileged user opens the machine up to attack because if the service is compromised, the attacker will be able to run any scripts *as that privileged user*. Perhaps you might want to consider engaging the assistance of someone who can help you learn the ropes in real life.

Comment: So, plain and simple: can I use my browser with localhost to do some testings with db and record in MySQL or I have to just use 
sqlite < my.dat sent from my perl script?